# getting HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, http, service

This is my code. I am receiving HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request. Not sure if I did something wrong here.

```
try {
                //client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                client=HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
                get = new HttpGet(queryURL.toString());
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
                if(HttpStatus.SC_OK!=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
                    throw new ServiceException(this, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"", response.getStatusLine().toString());
                }
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    json.append(line);
                }
```

The error message.

ServiceException: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Maybe you should check the `queryURL` used in the request.

Comment: Check Setting 'Content-Type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out reason of the `Bad Request` firstly you should see the response text. You can write as following:

```
client=HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
get = new HttpGet(queryURL.toString());
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder responseAsString = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                responseAsString.append(line);
            }

if(HttpStatus.SC_OK!=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
      throw new ServiceException(this, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"", response.getStatusLine().toString() + ", cause: " + responseAsString);
}
```